# Quickbooks Signature Invalid

Tags: php, yii2, quickbooks

I need to integrate Quickbooks API in Yii2 framework, I have been using this package to integrate the API - https://packagist.org/packages/rangka/quickbooks

Whenever the code tried to connect the Quickbooks this says oauth_problem=signature_invalid

Mainly this occurs when I proceed at step no. 3 of this package - https://packagist.org/packages/rangka/quickbooks

```
$connector = new \Rangka\Quickbooks\Connect();
$result = $connector->connect($_GET);
```

I do not get proper results in `$_GET` request.

Because I am using Yii framework for this, I would need to use Yii::$app->request->get()

instead of $_GET

Answer (score 0):

In yii framework we need to append "/" in front of the quickbooks package classes while creating an object.